# Throws FileNotFoundException when creating scanner from file

Tags: java

I'm trying to show a file open dialog and then create a scanner to read the selected file. When I run my code it throws a `FileNotFoundException` which doesn't make sense to me since it throws the exception before it opens the file selector window.

```
package files;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.Scanner;
import javax.swing.JFileChooser;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class FileManipulations {

    public static void main (String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> runGUI());
    }

    public static void runGUI () {
        JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();
        chooser.showOpenDialog(null);
        File file = chooser.getSelectedFile();
        System.out.println(file.exists());
        Scanner fromFile = new Scanner(file);
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you post the stack trace from with the error message?  Make sure there is a call to printStackTrace() in the catch block.

Comment: How do you know that a file has been selected?  `chooser` will return an `int` indiciating if the user closed the dialog (via cancel or the close button) or clicked the "approve" button, you should be checking this.  Try adding `System.out.println(file.exists())` to see if the file actually exists

Comment: I don't think the exception is thrown by Scanner.

Comment: @MadProgrammer I added `System.out.println(file.exists());` and it returned true to the console.

Comment: Consider providing a [runnable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which demonstrates your problem. This is not a code dump, but an example of what you are doing which highlights the problem you are having. This will result in less confusion and better responses

Comment: @zzy I thought the exception was being thrown by the scanner because when I commented out that line of code it opened up the file window.

Comment: Please print the file's path.

Comment: @MadProgrammer I added a runnable example. Hopefully that will clear up the confusion.

Comment: @spencerlarry You could has a compiler error, meaning that it shouldn't even run.  You need to either catch or re-throw the exception which `Scanner(File)` throws

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Starting with your example code...

```
import java.io.File;
import java.util.Scanner;
import javax.swing.JFileChooser;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class FileManipulations {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> runGUI());
    }

    public static void runGUI() {
        JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();
        chooser.showOpenDialog(null);
        File file = chooser.getSelectedFile();
        System.out.println(file.exists());
        Scanner fromFile = new Scanner(file);
    }
}
```

You are getting a compiler error because `Scanner(File)` can throw a `FileNotFoundException`

You either need to `catch` the exception or re-throw it, for example...

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.Scanner;
import javax.swing.JFileChooser;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class FileManipulations {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> runGUI());
    }

    public static void runGUI() {
        JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();
        switch (chooser.showOpenDialog(null)) {
            case JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION:
                File file = chooser.getSelectedFile();
                System.out.println(file.exists());
                try (Scanner fromFile = new Scanner(file)) {
                    while (fromFile.hasNextLine()) {
                        String text = fromFile.nextLine();
                        System.out.println(text);
                    }
                } catch (FileNotFoundException exp) {
                    exp.printStackTrace();
                }
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

You might also like to have a look at [How to Use File Choosers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/filechooser.html) and make sure you are checking the return result of `showOpenDialog` so you know how the dialog was closed

Also, have a look at [The try-with-resources Statement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) for more details about how to manage your resources

Answer (score 0):

I think your code is somewhat as follows :

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.Scanner;

import javax.swing.*;

public class Solutiokn {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
           JFileChooser fileChoose = new JFileChooser();
           fileChoose.showOpenDialog(null);
           File file = fileChoose.getSelectedFile();
           System.out.println(file.exists());
           try {
            Scanner fromFile = new Scanner(file);
            while(fromFile.hasNextLine())
                System.out.println(fromFile.nextLine());
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

Ok now this works just fine. Only point when I have issue is when I do not pick a file in the file chosser and just click cancel. When this happens the scanner itself is not created as value in "file" is null. I suggest adding a check manually to see if any file was selected or not like if(file==null) System.out.println("Please select a file"); or throw your own exception. If you don't probably a sudden nullPointerException will pop up.
Edit : As madProgrammer pointed out file.getName() would rather instead throw nullPointerException I tried changing it to file.exists() that still throws Exception if file was not selected. So instead maybe checking file==null is better. file.exists() checks if file denoted by this pathname exists but if we never inititalized it i.e just cancelled in file chooser then it does not help.

Comment: You might like to have a look at [How to Use File Choosers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/filechooser.html) and make appropriate use of the return results from the chooser.  If a `File` is `null` checking it's `name` property will cause a `NullPointerException` and I'm not sure if you can actually create a `File` object with a `null` `name`